# Integrate Trading view with Angular 10 universal SSR

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, tradingview-api, datafeed

Hi I have integrated trading view libraries for Angular 10 client side rendering. Recently I want to do SEO for my website so had implement trading view in Angular 10 universal.

Here main issue is when I load trading view first time it loads perfectly. But when i load for the second time it gives "window is not defined" error[image: integrated console error]

I have imported datafeeds in index.html [image: index.html]

please check my ts.app.config [image: ts.app.config]

what more do i have to add to make it work on angular 10 universal??

Comment: Use `domino` to provide a mock for `window`

Comment: have created a windowservice to handle window object throughout the project. But trading view libraries contains multiple window objects in .min (minified) scripts. How to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, you can try using `domino` to provide a mock for `window` object, especially for 3rd party libs

**server.ts**

```
//imports ...

const domino = require('domino');
const win = domino.createWindow('/path/to/your/project/dist/client/index.html');
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;

//...
//start express server as usual
```

Comment: Working like a charm!!...Thanks David